# Change woocommerce subscription "shop" link inside my account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm a newbie in coding and currently using woocommerce subscription plugin and wanted to change the default "shop" if I don't have any subscription. I want it to link to a specific product instead of the shop.

I want to change the red part:
[image: I want to change the red part]

Below are the current code for this section:

```
<?php
        // translators: placeholders are opening and closing link tags to take to the shop page
        printf( esc_html__( 'Anda masih belum melanggan. Mula melanggan %sdi sini%s.', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ), '<a href="' . esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_message_store_url', get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) ) ) . '">', '</a>' );
        ?>
    </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to change the `example.com/shop` into something like `example.com/product-category/myproduct`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you will need:

- A conditional function that detect if the current user has an active subscription
- A custom function hooked in `woocommerce_subscriptions_message_store_url` filter hook, where **you will define your new URL linked to your product**.

Here is the code:

```
// Conditional function detecting if the current user has an active subscription
function has_active_subscription( $user_id=null ) {
    // if the user_id is not set in function argument we get the current user ID
    if( null == $user_id )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get all active subscrptions for a user ID
    $active_subscriptions = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $user_id,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_subscription', // Subscription post type
        'post_status' => 'wc-active', // Active subscription
    ) );
    // if user has an active subscription
    if( ! empty( $active_subscriptions ) ) return true;
    else return false;
}


// Change woocommerce subscription “shop” link inside my account page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_message_store_url', 'custom_subscriptions_message_store_url', 10, 1 );
function custom_subscriptions_message_store_url( $url ){

    // If current user has NO active subscriptions 
    if( ! has_active_subscription() ){

        // HERE Define below the new URL linked to your product.
        $url = home_url( "/product-category/myproduct/" );
    }
    return $url;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec Great help! Solved my problem. I have used another code of yours as well which you comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661356/i-want-to-configure-the-subscription-endpoint-located-in-my-account-page-of-wooc .My other question would be, how do I bold the above custom label and move it to the top in the navigation list?

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec Thank you for the advise. I have created a new thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889365/i-want-to-sort-the-navigation-order-inside-woocommerce-my-account-page Thanks in advance