# Reorder menu items in Woocommerce My Account section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to move the "Langgan" menu label *(for subscriptions key)* on top of "Dashboard" and bold the "Langgan".

Currently I'm using the code below for "Langgan" part inside my theme `function.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'rename_my_account_menu_items', 0, 15 );
function rename_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {

    // HERE set your new label name for subscriptions
    $items['subscriptions'] = __( 'Custom label', 'woocommerce' );

    return $items;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a custom label for `'subscriptions'` key and reorder menu items to get it at the beginning, try this instead *(this will replace your function)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'rename_my_account_menu_items', 100, 1 );
function rename_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    $ordered_items = array();

    // HERE set your custom label name for 'subscriptions' key in this array
    $subscription_item = array( 'subscriptions' => __( 'Langgan', 'woocommerce' ) );

    // Remove 'subscriptions' key / label pair from original $items array
    unset( $items['subscriptions'] );

    // merging arrays
    $items = array_merge( $subscription_item, $items );

    return $items;
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

---

To make "Langgan" Bold you should need to add in your styles.css file located in your active theme, the following CSS rule:

```css
li.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--subscriptions {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

OR

```css
nav.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation > ul > li:first-child {
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec The sorting work great. However, the navigation still shown Subscriptions instead of Langgan. I have replaced the previous code with the new one given above. Any other step I'm missing?

Comment: @TheNewbie **Update** -The problem was in your hooked function (the hook priority and the number of arguments are wrong). I have changed `, 0, 15 );` to `, 100, 1 );` … now it works just fine, try it please…

Comment: It work great! Thank you for the help. Appreciate it!